# Add values in new column based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql and using sql server 2019. I have 3 columns- Code, Rep, Area in a table.  Based on certain conditions in these columns, I need to create 2 new columns- Business and Plant with values. I have tried to use if-then-else and case-when statements. But they are giving error when I add multiple conditions. Please help with the query to create these new columns in the basis of conditions below. Hope this table below helps-

select *,Business case when code in ('A231', B343') and Rep='Alex' then Business='Steel' else Null End as Business
Error - Incorrect Syntax near keyword 'case'

Input table -

| Code | Rep | Area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A231 | Alex | Del |
| B343 | Alen | Mum |

| Condition | Bus | Plant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Code=['A231','B343'] and Rep=['Alex'] and Area=['Del'] | Steel | EXR |
| Code=['A231','B343'] and Rep=['Alen'] and Area=['Mum'] | Iron | EXR |

Output table -

| Code | Rep | Area | Business | Plant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A231 | Alex | Del | Steel | EXR |
| B343 | Alen | Mum | Iron | EXR |

Comment: Show us the code you have tried and the error you received. It's not quite clear to me what you're trying to do, since you can't "conditionally add a column" depending on the values in different rows. The columns that exist in a table are the same for every row.

Comment: Please refer to the input tables and output tables. I have added the conditions based on which the new columns need to be added.

Comment: Edit your question and include the code you have tried and the error you received when you tried it.

Comment: Where's "Iron" coming from?

Comment: I think the real problem here is you're storing denormalised data in a non-standard format (such as XML or JSON). T-SQL is *terrible* at string manipulation and you want to no only read the string as a dataset, but also manipulate it and (where applicable) turn into multiple rows. I would suggest that where ever the data for your column `condition` is coming you, you change your design and application to use normalised data. Otherwise, at least use some kind of standardised medium that SQL Server can consume (again, such as JSON or XML). This task, as it stands, shouldn't be done in T-SQL.

Comment: @allmhuran select *,Business case when code in ('A231', B343') and Rep='Alex' then Business='Steel' else Null End as Business

Comment: There is a missing single quote in the `IN(x, y)` part, and the Case is wrong too

Answer (score 1):

If you were to store these conditions in a proper format, such as JSON, you could use `OPENJSON` to crack open the arrays and semi-join that to get the correct rows.

For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO Conditions
  (Bus, Plant, Condition)
VALUES
  ('Steel', 'EXR', '{"Code":["A231","B343"], "Rep":["Alex"], "Area":["Del"]}'),
  ('Iron', 'EXR', '{"Code":["A231","B343"], "Rep":["Alen"], "Area":["Mum"]}');
```

```sql
SELECT
  i.*,
  c.Bus,
  c.Plant
FROM Input i
JOIN Conditions c
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.Condition)
      WITH (
        Code nvarchar(max) AS JSON,
        Rep  nvarchar(max) AS JSON,
        Area nvarchar(max) AS JSON
      ) j
   ON i.Code IN (SELECT j2.value FROM OPENJSON(j.Code) j2)
  AND i.Rep  IN (SELECT j2.value FROM OPENJSON(j.Rep ) j2)
  AND i.Area IN (SELECT j2.value FROM OPENJSON(j.Area) j2);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b805110811aa92c8abde4290367a4bb)

The first `OPENJSON` returns a schema of the three arrays.

Then you use `OPENJSON` again without a schema to return each array element.

You can modify your current data with this code, to return proper JSON

```sql
UPDATE Conditions
SET Condition = '{"' +
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
        Condition,
        ' and ',
        ',"'
      ),
      '=[',
      '":['
    ),
    '''',
    '"'
  ) + '}';
```

Comment: Thanks @charlieface for the detailed explanation. However, I need to add the 2 columns - Business and  Plant. Condition is a criteria on the basis on which these 2 new columns will be added.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you look at the fiddle you will see those two columns coming back from the join, is that not what you wanted?